# Output required in float data type from Logistic regression

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am using `sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression`. The features in my data are in 'int' and 'float' values both. While the outcome is also of float data type, the final y_predict is printed in integer values. I am using the following code-

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size = 0.30)
y=y.astype('float')  
X_train.shape
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
Lr=LogisticRegression()
Lr.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_predict=Lr.predict(X_test)   
df1=pd.DataFrame({"Actual":y_test, "Predicted":y_predict})
```

I want the actual and predicted values in float but it is giving the output in int data type. How can I get exact actual values of y_test(which are of float type, my input data) and so the predicted values also in float data type.
Sample output(eg.) :
Actual  Predicted
2   2
Required(eg.):
Actual  Predicted
1.234  1.234

Comment: Encode continuous values using [LabelEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html), or Discretizer them using [KBinsDiscretizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.KBinsDiscretizer.html)

Answer (score 1):

Logistic regression provides a constant output. If you want a continuous output consider using a model like linear regression. Also consider using `predict_proba` instead of `predict`. This will give you the probabilities for the target in array form.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I got the y_predict in float data type by using Linear Regression instead of Logistic Regression. But still, the y_actual is still coming in int data type. For eg. Actual=2, Predicted= 2.149882.  Also on using the Linear regression model and predict_proba(as you suggested) I am getting an error- 
AttributeError: 'LinearRegression' object has no attribute 'predict_proba'

Comment: @Srishino Yes, the linear regression model doesn't have a `predict_proba` attribute but the logistic regression model does. I see `y=y.astype('float')` was used in your question. If you want this to affect `y_actual`, you need to have this line before `train_test_split`

Comment: Thanks, Its printing in float now. But the problem is that it is not printing my actual input data that I initially stored in y as 'outcome'. For eg. my data is like- 2.30456, it is giving only 2.0, 3.0 values not the actual values from my data file.